# HTML Email via VBA with bullets

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am struggling to get my HTML formatting correct on an automated email generated through VBA. I have never used HTML before in my life, so this is a totally new thing for me... I have tried to research online already but I just can't make sense of this.

```
.HTMLBody = "<style> body{color:black;font-family:Calibri;font-size: 11pt;}" & "<HTML><body>Dear " & Addressee & ",<br><br>As you would be aware, the...<br><br>Please find attached spreadsheet showing:<br><br>&emsp;&mdash;&emsp;Example list 1. <br>&emsp;&mdash;&emsp;Example list 2. <br>&emsp;&mdash;&emsp;Example list 3.<br><br> <b>Kindly reply to ALL indicating...</b><br><br> Regards,<br><br>" & Signature
```

The problem with the above is that it doesn't automatically indent the lines if they subsequently move into a second row as I have "created" fake bullets. Also, this code above is terribly basic (reflecting my lack of understanding :/) - but I essentially want to find a way to have a bunch of text, list 3 bullets keeping all the formatting as would be in the case of normal bullets (i.e. indent the lines) and then have a conclusion and normal end of email.

Any chance someone will be able to assist me with the HTML code to have bullets..? I have cleared out a lot of the text in the above code due to confidential information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use an [Ordered List](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) which uses the layout of:

```
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Where the `<ol>` tag stands for Ordered List and the `<li>` tags stand for List Item. The above code produces the following:

> 1. Item 1
> 2. Item 2
> 3. Item 3

Alternatively, if you don't want numbers and just want bullet points you can use an Unordered List which uses the same layout except the `<ol>` tag changes to `<ul>`:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

And looks like this:

> - Item 1
> - Item 2
> - Item 3